# Jquery MVC3 onvalidation event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple for with a password + username combination made with MVC3 and using the validation plugins from jquery.

When I have an error I want to show a special container containing all the errors, currently I am doing this like this:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    $('.message').fadeOut();
    if (!$(this).valid()) {
        $('.message').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Only this doesn't work when you are typing in the username or password field, jquery will do validation while you are typing, resulting in an empty error container.

Is there an event so I can monitor realtime if a form is valid or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the `keyup` event:

```
$('form input').keyup(function() {
    $('.message').fadeOut();
    if (!$(this).closest('form').valid()) {
        $('.message').fadeIn();
    }
});​
```

Comment: Yes that is a good suggestion, I would have to make the code a bit more robust, now the container would keep fading in and out ofcourse :-)

Comment: After checking around a bit more, I conclude this is the only valid answer ;)